# Tailwind Layout

Tags: flexbox, tailwind-css

How can I create this layout with flex boxes in Tailwind?
On mobile, blocks should be stacked one above the other.
On desktop, the block 2 should take full screen height, block 1 should be height of it's own content and block 3 should take the rest of screen height.

[mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upRsi.jpg)
[desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFWRx.jpg)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Something like [this](https://play.tailwindcss.com/JVNpRylfKQ)?

Comment: Looks pretty good! I didn't know about  sm:grid-rows-[min-content,1fr]. Thank you very much !

Comment: this comes with CSS property [min-content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-content) and Tailwind's [arbitrary](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#using-arbitrary-values) values. With this JIT mode you can write any CSS as class - some kind of inline styling

Answer (score 1):

As @Ihar Aliakseyenka commented:

You can use the following code:

```
<div class="grid h-screen sm:grid-cols-4 sm:grid-rows-[min-content,1fr]">
  <div class="text-center bg-red-500 sm:row-span-2 m-2">Block 2</div>

  <div class="order-first m-2 bg-yellow-300 text-center sm:order-none sm:col-span-3">Block 1</div>

  <div class="bg-blue-500 m-2 text-center sm:col-span-3">Block 3</div>
</div>
```

**Output**

Desktop :

[image]

Mobile:

[image]